# SQL Server indexes Work Sometimes

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, sql-server-2017, statistics, nonclustered-index

So I have the following indexes on my table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [$5] ON [dbo].[Record Link]
(
    [Company] ASC,
    [Record ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [$6] ON [dbo].[Record Link]
(
    [Notify] ASC,
    [Record ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [$7] ON [dbo].[Record Link]
(
    [Company] ASC,
    [Type] ASC,
    [Link ID] ASC,
    [Record ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [$8] ON [dbo].[Record Link]
(
    [Company] ASC,
    [Type] ASC,
    [Record ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [bain_test] ON [dbo].[Record Link]
(
    [Record ID] ASC,
    [Type] ASC,
    [Company] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [$4] ON [dbo].[Record Link]
(
    [Notify] ASC,
    [Company] ASC,
    [Link ID] ASC,
    [To User ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The Problem is that some of the indexes only get used some times.
As an example look at this query and the Execution plan, you can see that it is executed within the EXISTS but it is not executed for the rest of the query.
Both where clauses are identical.

[image]

Here is that queries statistics time and IO:

```
*SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Record Link'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.*

*(1 row affected)*

*SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.*
*(1 row affected)*

*Table 'Record Link'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1017129, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 1, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.*

*(1 row affected)*

*SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1969 ms,  elapsed time = 1963 ms.*
```

I don't have the option of changing the query as it from an ERP system and I'm trying to optimize the speed.

And while we are here there are a few different variations for querying this table.

Here are another one that don't use the indexes at all.

With this one things are strange, so i first tried having an index that uses fields: Record ID, Company, this didn't work until I created a new index and made it: Company, Record ID.

I Did this yesterday and it was working, but this morning in the profiler its not using the index again.

```
SELECT  TOP (1) 
    "timestamp","Link ID",
    "Record ID",
    "URL1",
    "URL2",
    "URL3",
    "URL4",
    "Description",
    "Type",
    DATALENGTH("Note"),
    "Created",
    "User ID",
    "Company",
    "Notify",
    "To User ID" 
FROM 
    "Live".dbo."Record Link" WITH(UPDLOCK)  
WHERE 
    ("Record ID"=@0 AND "Company"=@1) 
ORDER BY 
    "Link ID" ASC 
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

With this one, i really just cant figure it out, i thought the index with company,notify,User ID would work:

```
SELECT TOP (@0)
    "timestamp", "Link ID", "Record ID",
    "URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4",
"Description", "Type", DATALENGTH("Note"), "Created", "User ID",
    "Company", "Notify", "To User ID"
FROM "Live_Replica".dbo."Record Link" WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
WHERE ("Link ID">@1
  AND (("Company"=@2 OR "Company"=@3)
  AND "Notify"=@4
  AND ("To User ID" COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI LIKE @5
    OR "To User ID" COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI LIKE @6)))
ORDER BY "Link ID" ASC
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN, FAST 50)
```

I Have tried googling for this issues but cant seem to find an answer at all.
All indexes are rebuilt every night and i don't shrink the database at all so that the indexes don't get fragmented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As an example look at this query and the Execution plan, you can see
>   that it is executed within the EXISTS but it is not executed for the
>   rest of the query. **Both where clauses are identical**.

Both `where` clauses are identical, but the `select` lists are not.

There is NO `covering index` for your queries among those shown in your question, except for those with `exists`.

For `exists` query it's important only to know if such a record (with `[Record ID]` = ..., `[Type]` = ...,`[Company]` = ...) exists, so the server can only control your index `[bain_test]` that includes all these fields as `key fiels`.

For the second `query` you asked server for many other fields (see your `SELECT` list) that are not included in this `index` and in no other `index`, so if the server chose your `index` it had to do `lookups` to a base table, and since `statistics` cannot be used in your case (you used `oprimize for unknown` hint), server estimated the number of returned rows as too many and chosed to do a `scan`. `Scan` at least is continuos reading while `lookups` are random and they cost.

The same is for your third query. None of the indexes is `covering`, you `select` the fields that are not included in your `indexes`, and even if it seems that this query should return only one row, it's not a `random` row, your `top` has `order by` clause, so all the records should be read first and ten `sorted`.

I think you should examing your missimg indexes from

`sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups`,
`sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats`,

```
sys.dm_db_missing_index_details
```

to decide what `indexes` you should create.

And also take a look on `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` to find out `unused indexes`.

Your indexes are very similar, and your conditions are similar too, at least all the queryis have `Record ID` AND `Company`. Why don't you think that your `clustered index` (on [Record ID] I suppose) is not optimal? It's already sorted on one of your conditions, it is very probably `unique` and it's always `covering`. It's very probably that your indexes are not used at all.

And please update your quastion with `clustered index` definition.

Comment: There is no order operation in the second query plan so the clustered index must be on `[Link ID]` I think.

Comment: Hi sepupic,
Thanks for the explanation, Its not optimal because the datatype is of varbinary. so its a long key in many cases, but not much I can do about that.
I also read that using include just wastes space and they you should only use the fields in the where clause, this has work until now. It also works on all other queries.
I can't use the include in the one case as there is an image field "Note".

Comment: >>>Its not optimal because the datatype is of varbinary. so its a long key in many cases<<< Your clustered index key is ALWAYS presented in all your nonclustered indexes too

Comment: >>>I also read that using include just wastes space<<< Creating many useless  indexes is not only waste of space, it's also a const of mantenance of those indexes on every DML operation

Comment: How would i use the include since there is an image field? i tried it with all the other fields in the include with no success?

Comment: If you want to include a field of image type in your index you should pass from deprecated image type to varbinary(max), the best way to do it is to make select into new table with the cast of image as varbinary. I don't think it will help you anyway, BLOB fields are always slow to be retrieved, I think your problem is not lack of indexes, your problem is BLOBs

Comment: The only option to make query optimizer use the index is to replace `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. Then, depending on statistics, the index could be used if it doesn't cause a huge number of key lookup operations.

Comment: I Appreciate all the help guys, its the OPTION(RECOMPILE) that was the issue. i shall request with the systems developers to change the queries.

Comment: >>>its the OPTION(RECOMPILE) that was the issue<<< Your queries were WITHOUT this option, on contrary, it could HELP to find the optimal plan, as in this case your parameters and even variables are sniffed on every execution. You instead used (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN), that excludes use of statistics, and where there can be only one row returned for some certain values of variables, server estimates much more rows as it has no idea about the values passed

Comment: Sorry, seems there is a misunderstanding, I meant not having it in was the issue.